# How do I turn a USB keyboard into a bluetooth keyboard with the Pi?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

Is it possible to use a Raspberry Pi to turn a USB keyboard into a Bluetooth keyboard with a Bluetooth dongle to connect to other devices? If it is possible, I would like to know how...

Comment: http://www.linuxuser.co.uk/tutorials/emulate-a-bluetooth-keyboard-with-the-raspberry-pi

Answer (score 1):

The [hidclient](http://anselm.hoffmeister.be/computer/hidclient/index.html.en) program should be able to do what you want; however, you will probably need to build it from sources yourself.

Comment: Seems hopeful - Haven't tested it yet but will do...